# when update data in edit post it insert duplicate courses

Tags: jquery, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, linq-to-entities

**In edit view when i edit in name of employee then click save button to save
it insert courses exist again so that courses  found two times.**

image below show

[when update it duplicate courses](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zet4B.jpg)

I have this model Cusomemp2

this is custom model using for update data in two table

employee and employeecourse

```
 public class Cusomemp2
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<EmployeeCourse> empcourses { get; set; }
 
    }

}
```

when i need to update employee and employeecourse table

i write following code in httppost

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(Cusomemp2 custom)
        {
            Employee e1 = db.Employees.Find(custom.Id);
            e1.Name = custom.Name;
            
            e1.EmployeeCourses = custom.empcourses;
           
            db.SaveChanges();

            return View();
        }
```

in edit view i write jquery as following

```
var index = 0;
            $("#CourseId").change(function () {

                var id = $(this).val();
                var txt = $("#CourseId option:selected").text();
                $("#tb").append("<tr><td><input type = 'hidden' name='empcourses[" + index + "].CourseId' value='" + id + "'/></td><td>" + txt + "</td><td><input type='button' value='remove' class='r'</td></tr>")

                index++;
            });
            $("#tb").on("click", ".r", function () {
                $(this).parent().parent().hide();
                $(this).parent().prev().prev().find("input").val("0");
            });
            button for save as following


<input type="submit" value="save" />
```

**updated**

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(Cusomemp2 custom)
        {
           
            var result = db.Employees
                 .Where(p => p.Id == custom.Id)
                 .Include(c => c.EmployeeCourses)
                 .FirstOrDefault();

            if (custom.empcourses.Any())
        {
            foreach (var ec in result.EmployeeCourses.ToList())//to remove existing EmployeeCourses
            {
                db.EmployeeCourses.Remove(ec);
                db.SaveChanges();

            }
        }

            result.Name = custom.Name;

            result.EmployeeCourses = custom.empcourses;
            db.SaveChanges();

            

            return View();
        }
```

**updated**

until now issue not solved the result of this code above remove all courses

so that i add new link for remove

[how to delete assigned courses only not all courses for employee](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39509938/exception-error-when-click-save-button-to-removed-courses)

Comment: where you call `Edit()` method ? can you show that code too ?

Comment: are you mean edit get or what

Comment: by using which button you call `Edit()` method ?

Comment: by using save button the last button below of edit view in the bottom

Comment: using this `$("#tb").on("click", ".r", function () {` ?

Comment: no this button for hide courses selected if i need to remove

Comment: so then which button to `save` ?

Comment: i updated in original post it is last code line this is my button using for save

Comment: can you put a debug on the `Edit()` method and see whether it's being called 2 times when you press a `save` button ?

Comment: i check it call only one time

Comment: in this link all code exist what inside controller and view and http://www.mediafire.com/download/360yljihv9yki6p/edit_view.txt

Comment: i have error show     
I have error in first foreach in line result.EmployeeCourses it tell me task<employee>does not contain definition for method'EmployeeCourses' accepting first argument of type task<Employee>could not be found (are you missing assembly or directory reference

Comment: please see the update. http://stackoverflow.com/a/39502313/1077309

Comment: now code work but when i try to add new course then click save not save courses added

Answer (score 0):

You can try as shown below.

**Note :** Ef doesn't update child entries automatically. So yo have to do it manually as shown below.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(Cusomemp2 custom)
    {
       var result = db.Employees
                 .Where(p => p.Id == custom.Id)
                 .Include(c => c.EmployeeCourses)
                 .FirstOrDefault();

    if(custom.empcourses.Any())
     {
     foreach (var ec in result.EmployeeCourses.ToList())//to remove existing EmployeeCourses
       {
         db.EmployeeCourses.Remove(ec);
         db.SaveChanges();
       }
   }

      result.Name = custom.Name;
      result.EmployeeCourses = custom.empcourses;
      db.SaveChanges();

      return View();
     }
```

Comment: I have error in first foreach in line result.EmployeeCourses it tell me task<employee>does not contain definition for method'EmployeeCourses' accepting first argument of type task<Employee>could not be found (are you missing assembly or directory reference

Comment: can you show your latest code after the modification ?

Comment: i add latest code on update section in original post

Comment: can you put a debug and let me know what happen there?

Comment: debug in which section

Comment: i think coding above remaining to put savechanges in every foreach for add and remove after i put savechanges in every foreach for add and remove final result is it remove all for courses but cannot add again why cannot add again

Comment: when i put break point then add two courses it tell me count =2 in custom.empcourses

Comment: OK,you have to put another `db.SaveChanges();` after the final for loop and let me know the result then.

Comment: I make as you tell me IT GIVE me as result http://www.mediafire.com/view/kphdy5mkb546448/duplicate3.jpg

Comment: still you have an issue or what ?

Comment: can you remove `db.SaveChanges();` after the for loop and put that before the final for loop and let me know the result .? I.e. after this line `result.Name = custom.Name;`

Comment: same thing it give me count =2 in custom.empcourses and not save any courses added only remove all

Comment: no errors or exceptions ? what about `result.Name = custom.Name;` is that saved ?

Comment: result.Name = custom.Name; yes it saved

Comment: after update if i add new course it add without any problem but remove not working

Comment: if i select from courses drop down it will add without problem but if i not add course using drop down it delete all

Comment: if i add any course it saved only problem in remove

Comment: if im not added any course then click save button it will delete all it only save selected from drop down

Comment: please see the latest update and let me know the result now.

Comment: No .  can you help me in remove code above if you notice in jquery any course i remove i give him value 0 so that if i need to remove i must tell him in code if course id =0 remove it but i dont know how

Comment: i test it same before if i using remove button to remove one course then click save it remove all

Comment: did that work correctly on your old code ? I mean remove part ?

Comment: i add another question for remove in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39509938/exception-error-when-click-save-button-to-removed-courses