# how to delete assigned courses only not all courses for employee

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-5

**Problem**

In edit view when i click remove course then click save it remove all course not

only i selected for remove

**Details**

if i have courses a,b,c for employee name michel then remove course a

and click save it delete all courses b,c also deleted

I need actually delete assigned for remove only meaning remove a and remaining

b,c. see image below it show what i need clearly

model Cusomemp2

```
 public class Cusomemp2
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }//employee
        public string Name { get; set; }//employee
        public List<EmployeeCourse> empcourses { get; set; }//employeecourse

    }
```

in edit http post i need when click save button remove only assigned for delete

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(Cusomemp2 custom)
        {

            var result = db.Employees
                 .Where(p => p.Id == custom.Id)
                 .Include(c => c.EmployeeCourses)
                 .FirstOrDefault();

            if (custom.empcourses.Any())
        {
//in this foreach remove courses(not success)
            foreach (var ec in result.EmployeeCourses.ToList())//to remove existing EmployeeCourses
            {
                db.EmployeeCourses.Remove(ec);
                db.SaveChanges();

            }
        }

            return View();
        }
```

when click remove course it give value 0 for hidden course

the following show list of courses in view model

```
            var index = 0;
            $("#CourseId").change(function () {

                var id = $(this).val();
                var txt = $("#CourseId option:selected").text();
                $("#tb").append("<tr><td><input type = 'hidden' name='empcourses[" + index + "].CourseId' value='" + id + "'/></td><td>" + txt + "</td><td><input type='button' value='remove' class='r'</td></tr>")

                index++;
            });
            $("#tb").on("click", ".r", function () {
                $(this).parent().parent().hide();
                $(this).parent().prev().prev().find("input").val("0");
            });
```

Comment: can any one help me in that if possible

Comment: The code in the `foreach` loop in your POST method deletes ALL courses (what are y9ou expecting to happen?)

Comment: i need to delete only that i click remove for it not delete all

Comment: what i need actually if i have 3 courses a,b,c for employee michel and remove course a then click save button delete only course a from database after click save not remove all courses a,b,c from database

Comment: if you see image above step2 i remove c++ then click save button when open this employee again it have nothing meaning it not delete course assigned for remove it remove all so that i need to modify this code how to do that

Comment: Considering [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39187549/selected-district-not-retrieved-for-employee-in-edit-view-get#comment65733735_39187549), I see no point wasting my time.

Comment: so that what i do now

Comment: can you tell me if i need to delete only assigned courses what modify in code i will do

Comment: can any one help me in answering this question